# How to maintain state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a text box with some text which I get after doing ajax call.
When ever a user keys some text I dispatch the value to state.
This renders the current text area and cursor goes to front of the line.

How can I avoid re-rendering. How should I maintain state.

```
class Design extends React.Component{

constructor(){
    super();
}


handleMessageChange(e){
    let msg = e.target.innerText;
    this.props.dispatch({type:'design_changed',designObj:{property:'message',value:msg}})
}
 render(){
    return  (

      <React.Fragment>

          <Panel header="Message" key="2">
            <div>
              <div className="userscoop-content-editable-cls" contentEditable="true" onKeyUp={this.handleMessageChange.bind(this)}>{this.props.message}</div>
            </div>
          </Panel>

      </React.Fragment>
 }

function mapStateToProps(state){
   let settings = state.HelloBar.template.settings;
   return {
      background_color: settings.background_color,
      action_color:settings.action_color,
      message:settings.message,
      button_color:settings.button_color,
      input_placeholder:settings.input_placeholder,
      goal:state.HelloBar.goal
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method and compare the new and old state you can cancel the render.

Alternatively you could first try PureComponent and see if that works.

If you still have problems might consider looking into saving the cursor state also. [[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608293/2350085)]

Comment: Hi ! like this return nextProps['message'] != this.state['message'] .Where I set state using this.setState({message:msg}) and then dispatch the value to store . It triggers two call is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use components's `shouldComponentUpdate()` method to define whether or not it should rerender when some prop changes. You can write to to ignore this change.

Comment: Hi ! like this return nextProps['message'] != this.state['message'] .Where I set state using this.setState({message:msg}) and then dispatch the value to store . It triggers two call is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Redux-Form,if you are dealing with components which requires continuous action on fields.
Or use document.addEventListener in every actions which you fire by passing keyUp or keyDown