# How to handle onChange value in date? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple date input component, i just stuck when change the value of it. Because it always print value "1970-01-01".

Somebody knows how to do it. would appreciate thanks.

Here is my codes:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

const DateInput = ({ className = style.defaultSize, onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

  const onChangeDate = (date) => {
    const newDate = moment(date.timeStamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    setValue(newDate);
    console.log(newDate); //always log "1970-01-01"
  };

  return (
    <input
        type="date"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChangeDate}
     />
  );
};

export default DateInput;
```

Comment: The question is missing details about the problem. Please elaborate on your problem so that i can underatand

Comment: `date.timeStamp` should be `date.target.value` in the `onChangeDate` function. `const newDate = moment(date.target.value).format("YYYY-MM-DD");`. [** SandBox:**](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sunset-10mi8?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That because we will get the input `value` inside the `event.target.value`

```js
  const onChangeDate = e => {
    const newDate = moment(new Date(e.target.value)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    setValue(newDate);
    console.log(newDate); //value picked from date picker
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

### I have extended your code and showed it away, you can try it or visit live code to [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-chebyshev-nf9dv?file=/src/App.js)!

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import Moment from "react-moment";


const DateInput = ({ className = style.defaultSize, onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

  const onChangeDate = (date) => {
    const newDate = setValue(moment(new Date(date.target.value)).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    setValue(newDate);
    console.log(newDate); //always log "1970-01-01"
  };

  return (
    <input
        type="date"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e)=>onChangeDate(e)}
     />
     
     <strong>MOMENT TIME:</strong>
      <br />
      <Moment format="DD-MM-YYYY">{value}</Moment>
  );
};

export default DateInput;
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Question slightly off topic, why is it that your example in Codesandbox doesn't have React's control input caret jumping to the end issue? I also made an example with a plain text input and it doesn't have that issue in that same sandbox. In my project I have an implementation very similar to yours but because of controlled input caret jumping, editing the date by text breaks.

Comment: @NikolasPafitis, I really don't understand your problem, hopefully, it's come from another issue in your code.

Comment: I'm referring to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000544/react-controlled-input-cursor-jumps The sandbox example you provided doesn't have it although it should afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the field value via `target` property of the `event` object of the input. So your code would change as below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

const DateInput = ({ className = style.defaultSize, onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

  const onChangeDate = ({ target }) => {
    const newDate = moment(target.value.timeStamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    setValue(newDate);
    console.log(newDate); //always log "1970-01-01"
  };

  return (
    <input
        type="date"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChangeDate}
     />
  );
};

export default DateInput;
```