# React JS i can't write in middle of inputs controlled by useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i realized that in every project i made, when i do a simple react input controlled by a useState hook, i can't write in middle of words of that input.

For example: i have "Hello people" text in the input, but when i try to write something between "Hello" and "people" words, react writes just one letter and then the write cursor goes to the final of the input, so, i can't write full words in middle of a text in a input

```
<Input css={{ width: '50%' }}
    underlined
    labelPlaceholder="Abreviatura"
    color="primary"
    value={EF_Abreviatura}
    onChange={(e) => setEF_Abreviatura(e.target.value.toLocaleUpperCase())}
/>
```

I don't know what is happening here, but i have a video too to be more explicit

https://youtu.be/HORVeJRxVsQ

Comment: Does it happen when you remove .toLocaleUpperCase()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React controlled input cursor jumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000544/react-controlled-input-cursor-jumps)

Comment: im trying to use that solution, thanks for the reply

Comment: No, it didn't work, i tried putting (e) => {e.target.selectionStart = cursor} on onFocus parameter, but it didn't work, i also saved the position of the cursor on the onChange variable, didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the cursor state separately. You can achieve it using [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) hook wrapped as a custom hook. which does the cursor correction before the next browser paint.

This `useRunAfterUpdate` custom hook can be called with any function you like to run before browser paint happens (in your case after the text has updated).

```js
const useRunAfterUpdate = () => {
  const afterPaintRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (afterPaintRef.current) {
      afterPaintRef.current();
      afterPaintRef.current = null;
    }
  });

  const runAfterUpdate = (fn) => {
    afterPaintRef.current = fn;
  };

  return runAfterUpdate;
};

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");

  const runAfterUpdate = useRunAfterUpdate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const input = e.target;
    const cursor = input.selectionStart;
    const text = input.value;

    const newText = text.toLocaleUpperCase();

    setState(newText);

    runAfterUpdate(() => {
      input.selectionStart = cursor;
      input.selectionEnd = cursor;
    });
  };

  return <input value={state} onChange={handleChange} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Hey there, your solution works only if i delete the toLocaleUpperCase function on the text const, for some reason, it works when its without that, but i need it on UpperCase, do you know what could be happening?

Comment: You can run and see it works, can you create a code sanbox with what you have now and link here ? Are you using a library for `Input` element if so mention it as well

Comment: im using NextUI for the `Input` element, but i tried with a normal `input` from react library and it's the same result, for some reason, your code when i try it on a sandbox it work, but in my project doesn't