# Modifying user input value in React controlled component

Tags: reactjs, state

I've been stuck on this error for a long time, so I would appreciate some help. Here is a minimally reproducible exmaple:

```js
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";

function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const focusHandler = () => {
        $("input").on("keypress", (e) => {
            let copy = value;
            if (e.key === ".") {
                e.preventDefault();
                copy += "    ";
                setValue(copy);
            }
        });
    };

    const blurHandler = (event) => {
        $("input").off("keypress");
        setValue(event.target.value);
    };

    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                value={value}
                onFocus={focusHandler}
                onBlur={blurHandler}
                onChange={changeHandler}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

On input focus, I'm adding an event listener to look for a `.` keypress and append a tab (4 spaces) to the input if it is pressed. But when I press `.` multiple times, the input gets stuck at the first tab, and doesn't move any further (e.g. input permanenetly shows 4 spaces). Using `console.log` shows me that the `value` state doesn't seem to be updating in `focusHandler` and reverts to the original value (`""`).

An important note is that switching to a class-based component with `this.state` makes it work. Any insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: Have you inspected the state with the React dev tools?

Comment: Why are you combining jQuery with React? This is a strange setup -- React already attaches listeners to the DOM elements, so tossing jQuery handlers on top of that just seems to add to the confusion.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I have. I haven't been able to get much more information out of the dev tools than I have with `console.log` statements

Comment: @ggorlen Admittedly, it's not the cleanest way to handle what I want to do. Do you think mixing jQuery and React is what's causing the error?

Comment: Even if it works, it strikes me as an antipattern. I mean, you have two listeners: `onChange => setValue(something);` and jQuery has `.on("keypress" => setValue(somethingElse)`. It's not clear to me how React is supposed to make sense of this since pressing a key will fire both change and keypress events. As an aside, [keypress is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event).

Comment: @ggorlen Hmm, I see what you're saying. What's a better way to approach this without adding event listeners? The `changeHandler` seems to be necessary to control the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix direct DOM manipulation, whether that's vanilla JavaScript or jQuery, with React. There is no need to add an event handler with jQuery here, because your methods are already event handlers. Just use them directly:

```
    const focusHandler = (e) => {
        // handle the event here!
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That actually makes a lot of sense.  The `event` parameter of an event listener already gives me everything I need.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, jQuery is the [wrong tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51304632/6243352). Bringing in jQuery is the same as calling DOM methods directly: it's circumventing React and adding additional listeners on top of the ones React already gives you. You can expect misbehavior if you're setting state from multiple handlers unrelated to React. Once you're in React, use the tools it gives you (refs, effects, handlers) to solve the problem.

Worst case scenario is when an approach *appears* to work, then fails in production, on other people's machines/browsers, when refactoring from classes to hooks or vice-versa, in different versions of React, or for 1 out of 1000 users. Staying well within the API React gives you better guarantees that your app will behave correctly.

#### [Controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

For manipulating the input value, you can use [both `onKeyDown` and `onChange` listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36522297/6243352). `onKeyDown` fires first. Calling `event.preventDefault()` inside of `onKeyDown` will block the change event and ensure only one call to `setState` for the controlled input value occurs per keystroke.

The problem with this the [input cursor moves to the end after the component updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199687/react-input-cursor-moves-to-the-end-after-update) (see relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/955)). One way to deal with this is to manually adjust the cursor position when you've made an invasive change to the string by adding state to keep track of the cursor and using a ref and `useEffect` to set `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties on the input element.

This causes a brief [blinking effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28922465/6243352) due to asynchrony after the render, so this isn't a great solution. If you're always appending to the end of the value, you assume the user won't move the cursor as other answers do, or you want the cursor to finish at the end, then this is a non-issue, but this assumption doesn't hold in the general case.

One solution is to use [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) which runs synchronously before the repaint, eliminating the blink.

With `useEffect`:

```js
const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(-1);
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const pad = ".    ";
  
  const onKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.code === "Period") {
      event.preventDefault();
      const {selectionStart: start} = event.target;
      const {selectionEnd: end} = event.target;
      const v = value.slice(0, start) + pad + value.slice(end);
      setValue(v);
      setCursor(start + pad.length);
    }
  };
  
  const onChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    setCursor(-1);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cursor >= 0) {
      inputRef.current.selectionStart = cursor;
      inputRef.current.selectionEnd = cursor;
    }
  }, [cursor]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>press `.` to add 4 spaces:</p>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

With `useLayoutEffect`:

```js
const {useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [cursor, setCursor] = useState(-1);
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const pad = ".    ";
  
  const onKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.code === "Period") {
      event.preventDefault();
      const {selectionStart: start} = event.target;
      const {selectionEnd: end} = event.target;
      const v = value.slice(0, start) + pad + value.slice(end);
      setValue(v);
      setCursor(start + pad.length);
    }
  };
  
  const onChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    setCursor(-1);
  };
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (cursor >= 0) {
      inputRef.current.selectionStart = cursor;
      inputRef.current.selectionEnd = cursor;
    }
  }, [cursor]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>press `.` to add 4 spaces:</p>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

#### [Uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Here's another attempt using an uncontrolled component. This doesn't have the blinking problem because the DOM element's `.value` property is synchronously set at the same time as the `.selectionStart` property and is rendered in the same repaint.

```js
const App = () => {
  const pad = ".    ";
  
  const onKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.code === "Period") {
      event.preventDefault();
      const {target} = event;
      const {
        value, selectionStart: start, selectionEnd: end,
      } = target;
      target.value = value.slice(0, start) + 
                     pad + value.slice(end);
      target.selectionStart = start + pad.length;
      target.selectionEnd = start + pad.length;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>press `.` to add 4 spaces:</p>
      <input
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```js
const changeHandler = (event) => {
        const key = event.nativeEvent.data;
        if (key === ".") {
            event.preventDefault();
            const initialValue = event.target.value.split(".")[0];
            console.log(initialValue);
            setValue(initialValue + "    ");
        } else {
            setValue(event.target.value);
        }
};
```